# Date and Time formatting

Tags: datetime

I have a date and time that works great

```
format=" %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a" prints out > December 2, 2017; 7:30 pm
```

However, in some instances, I don't have the time, but I still want to show the date. I will come back in few weeks and put the time in when its confirmed. In the date picker if I leave the date out it prints 12:00 am Is there a workaround for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
{if '{my_date_field format="%g:%i %a"}' == "12:00 am"}
{my_date_field format=" %F %j, %Y"} {!-- date without time --}
{if:else}
{my_date_field format=" %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"} {!-- date with time --}
{/if}
```